# Composer keeps overwriting .htaccess (and other files) every time I do anything

Tags: 8, composer

Every time I try to update anything using Composer, it overwrites a load of files. One of the files it overwrites is .htaccess, which I have customised, so I have to keep patching it all the time. Here's an example (below) of it doing this even when package I asked to update didn't need updating. I'm guessing it's because I used the "drupal/core-composer-scaffold" package to create the site. I did that because I was following these instructions: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies#composer-from-scratch.

What am I doing wrong, to make it keep scaffolding (if that's the word for it) repeatedly? Thanks.

```
~/sites/default$ composer update drupal/security_review
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package academicpuma/citeproc-php is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use seboettg/citeproc-php instead.
Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/container instead.
Package technosophos/LibRIS is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package zendframework/zend-diactoros is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-diactoros instead.
Package zendframework/zend-escaper is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-escaper instead.
Package zendframework/zend-feed is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-feed instead.
Package zendframework/zend-stdlib is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-stdlib instead.
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Scaffolding files for drupal/core:
  - Copy [project-root]/.editorconfig from assets/scaffold/files/editorconfig
  - Copy [project-root]/.gitattributes from assets/scaffold/files/gitattributes
  - Copy [web-root]/.csslintrc from assets/scaffold/files/csslintrc
  - Copy [web-root]/.eslintignore from assets/scaffold/files/eslintignore
  - Copy [web-root]/.eslintrc.json from assets/scaffold/files/eslintrc.json
  - Copy [web-root]/.ht.router.php from assets/scaffold/files/ht.router.php
  - Copy [web-root]/.htaccess from assets/scaffold/files/htaccess
  - Copy [web-root]/example.gitignore from assets/scaffold/files/example.gitignore
  - Copy [web-root]/index.php from assets/scaffold/files/index.php
  - Copy [web-root]/INSTALL.txt from assets/scaffold/files/drupal.INSTALL.txt
  - Copy [web-root]/README.txt from assets/scaffold/files/drupal.README.txt
  - Copy [web-root]/robots.txt from assets/scaffold/files/robots.txt
  - Copy [web-root]/update.php from assets/scaffold/files/update.php
  - Copy [web-root]/web.config from assets/scaffold/files/web.config
  - Copy [web-root]/sites/README.txt from assets/scaffold/files/sites.README.txt
  - Copy [web-root]/sites/development.services.yml from assets/scaffold/files/development.services.yml
  - Copy [web-root]/sites/example.settings.local.php from assets/scaffold/files/example.settings.local.php
  - Copy [web-root]/sites/example.sites.php from assets/scaffold/files/example.sites.php
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this, this is done by concept. You can either extend or patch `.htaccess` using the `extra/drupal-scaffold` section in your composer.json, [see docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-drupals-composer-scaffold#toc_4) Using this Drupal will then automatically add your modifications after scaffolding.

Comment: Just wait :).  This will be fixed on the next Drupal Core release (8.9). See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3103090

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's Drupal's Composer Scaffold. Listed as `"drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.8.0"` or a different version in your project's `composer.json` file.

To prevent certain scaffold files from being overwritten every time you run a Composer command you need to specify them one by one in the `"extra"` section of your project's `composer.json`. See the docs on [Excluding scaffold files](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-drupals-composer-scaffold#toc_6).

The following snippet prevents the `.htaccess` and the `development.services.yml` from being overwritten.

```
"drupal-scaffold": {
    "locations": {
        "web-root": "web/"
    },
    "file-mapping": {
        "[web-root]/.htaccess": false,
        "[web-root]/sites/development.services.yml": false
    }
},
```

---

But maybe you want to ensure you always get Drupal's latest `.htaccess` for security updates for example. For that you don't exclude this file from Drupal Scaffold but you patch it instead. See the docs on [Altering scaffold files](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-drupals-composer-scaffold#toc_4).

Create a patch of the `.htaccess` and maybe put it in a folder called "patches" in your project root. Then configure a `"post-drupal-scaffold-cmd"` in the `"scripts"` section of your `composer.json` file to have this patch applied to Drupal's core `.htaccess` every time Drupal scaffolding is triggered.

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "post-drupal-scaffold-cmd": [
        "cd web && patch -p1 < ../patches/htaccess-ssl.patch"
    ]
}
```

Comment: cweagans/composer-patches can also handle the last bit, which I think is still added by default in drupal-composer/drupal-project